# Scala - Running Two Functions in Parallel

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, scala-2.10

I have two functions `(f : Unit => T, g : Unit => U)` for some types `T, U`. I want to run these two functions in parallel (equivalently on different threads). I want the main thread to wait for the two function calls to terminate and also get the result of both function calls. I was wondering what the best way to do this in Scala was. I have looked into Actors and Parallel Collections but can't find a way to do what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at [Futures](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/finagle.html#futconcurrent) module. Its method *join* allows to wait for results of two concurrent computations with different types.